# Resolve PR Conflict in Azure DevOps without changing source branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

We have two restricted git branches in Azure DevOps,

- `test` branch for UAT environment
- `master` branch for Production Environment

The developers **can't** commit these branches **directly**, they must create PRs to merge their own branches. And they base their own branches to `master`.

If the PR is approved, then it will be merged to `test` branch, and deploy to UAT env. If the customer/user accepts the changes in the `test` branch, we merge these PRs to the `master` branch to deploy to prod env. PRs in the `test` branch **may not** accept by customer and then it won't merge to the `master` branch. So we can't rebase feature branches to `test` or we can't merge test to these feature branches because **not** every commit in `test` goes to `master`.

If a conflict occures when created PR for `test` branch, we must resolve this conflict without changing source branch, and the merge commit must be stay in `test` branch. We can't rebase to `test`, because as I said before that not every PR in `test` will merge to `master`. So we use this extension as a workaround but it is not useful like visual studio merge tool: [PR Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)

Are there any way to achieve this without using this extension and with using visual studio merge tool? Or could you suggest another way to resolving PR conflicts without committing extra merge commit to source branch?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the PR conflict EXtension also can resolve PR conflict without changing source branch.

As you can see, the source branch is branch1 and the target branch is master. There is a conflict in the PR.
[image]

In the Conflict tab, you can choose Take Source File to resolve the conflict and it will not change source branch.
[image]

After complete the PR, below are the master commits and the branch1 commits. And there are not any changes in source branch(branch1). The 
[image]
[image]

There is only one difference between resolving a merge conflict with visual studio merge tool and PR conflict extension. The branch history don't have the conflict resolution commit. But this is because the visual studio merge tool resolved the conflict on the local branch , and push the changed file to azure repo, so this only have one commit about update.

The PR conflict extension directly modifies the file in the azure repo, so the commit history will include the step of conflict resolution. 
[image]

Comment: Yes, we use the extension already. But it is not useful as visual studio merge tool. I wonder if someone has any other solution for this problem.

Comment: What effect or feature do you want? If it's convenient, can you provide a screenshot or sample to let me better understand your needs?Thanks :).

Comment: @FrankWang-MSFT I would love the feature to select a specific section with ease. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114338/azure-devops-resolve-merge-conflict-of-pull-request-in-visual-studio