# Azure DevOps Resolve Merge conflict of Pull Request in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

The Azure DevOps 'Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension' is missing a great feature that the visual studio conflict resolver does have. That is, being able to select specific sections easily. This makes larger conflicts much easier to resolve.

[image]

For this reason I would prefer to be able to use the Visual Studio conflict resolver for the Azure DevOps pull requests. Is it possible to create a pull request in Azure DevOps, and then resolve the conflicts of that specific pull request in Visual Studio?

I know I can start a merge from Visual studio, which allows me to resolve the conflicts and push the fixes. But this bypasses the pull request. Showing the message, 'All changes in this pull request have been already merged to the target branch.'
[image]
Starting or viewing pull requests from Visual Studio just opens Azure DevOps.

I have already looked at the following sources, and others.

- [Resolve PR Conflict in Azure DevOps without changing source branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391289/resolve-pr-conflict-in-azure-devops-without-changing-source-branch?rq=3)
- [Azure DevOps Resolve Pull Request Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473042/azure-devops-resolve-pull-request-conflict)
- [How to resolve merge conflicts with Azure Devops and Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175749/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-with-azure-devops-and-visual-studio-2019)
- [How do I resolve a pull request merge conflict in Azure Dev Ops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722185/how-do-i-resolve-a-pull-request-merge-conflict-in-azure-dev-ops?rq=3)
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#overview

Comment: "I know I can start a merge from Visual studio, which allows me to resolve the conflicts in it. But this bypasses the pull request." What do you mean by this bypasses the PR? What steps do you take after this (I assume you push your branch) and what happens to the PR?

Comment: @TTT Thanks for responding! You are correct, I push the merge and then you get the message. 'All changes in this pull request have been already merged to the target branch.' in Azure DevOps

Comment: OK. That explains it. I just added another answer with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra info in the comments provides the key:

> I push the merge and then you get the message. 'All changes in this pull request have been already merged to the target branch.' in Azure DevOps

Note in your PR, the source branch is `Feature/Testing` and the target branch is `main`. Since the message said the target branch was updated, that means you pushed the merge to `main` instead of your feature branch. This probably happened one of two ways:

1. You checked out `main`, merged in `Feature/Testing`, resolved the conflicts, and pushed `main`. (This is backwards.)
2. Instead you should checkout `Feature/Testing`, merge in `main`, resolve the conflicts, and then push to your remote branch `Feature/Testing`. If you do this merge properly, but push to `main` instead, then you will update the target branch instead of the source branch.

The solution is to make sure you push your branch to `Feature/Testing` and this will update the PR appropriately.

**Tip:** if you setup branch policies on `main`, a Pull Request will become required and you won't be able to push directly to `main` anymore. I highly recommend doing this.

**Side Note:** If you prefer to use rebase instead of merge, you can locally `git fetch`, `git switch Feature/Testing`, followed by `git rebase origin/main`. After doing this you will need to force push instead of a regular push: `git push --force-with-lease`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to merge `main` to `Feture/testing` to update it with last chages in VS. Then create pull request to main. Or use the last solution in your list:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#overview

This is extesion for Azure DevOps or. It adds the new tab `Conflits` to your PR. You may resolve all conflits in this tab without local merges.

[image]

[image]